# How to replace one field of one model object in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change tags for an object. I first filter for the object I'm looking for and I now don't don't know how to replace the field (usertags).

```
def change_tags(request, pk):
    file = Uploaded.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('usertags')
    # file = get_object_or_404(Uploaded, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChangeTagsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(file)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})

class ChangeTagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded
        fields = ['usertags']
```

Answer (score 0):

to change values of an object with `ModelForm` you need to provide `instance` paramater to this `ModelForm`

```
def change_tags(request, pk):
    file = get_object_or_404(Uploaded, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChangeTagsForm(request.POST, instance=file)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = ChangeTagsForm(instance=file)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```